# Create custom Bootstrap dropdown in WordPress navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to recreate the following in WordPress:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                   Menu
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Works <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Works</li>
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I currently have got the top level navigation to work with the following code:

```
    <?php 

        wp_nav_menu( array(

            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'container'         => 'nav',
            'container_class'   => 'navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
            'container_id'      => 'sidebar-wrapper',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav sidebar-nav'

        ) );

     ?>
```

But how do I add a dropdown with the correct 'data-toggle' and classes?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way you should be using. https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Place *wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php* in your wordPress theme folder and include it in to wordPress themes functions.php file

---

Template using

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
            </a>
    </div>

        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom classes and attributes would be added by using 'custom walker function'.
You have to add parameter walker to wordpress wp_nav_menu() function and call your instance by extending Walker_Nav_Menu.

```
 wp_nav_menu( 
   array(
     'container' =>false,
     'menu_class' => 'nav',
     'echo' => true,
     'before' => '',
     'after' => '',
     'link_before' => '',
     'link_after' => '',
     'depth' => 0,
     'walker' => new description_walker()
   )
 );
```

Add below code into your theme's function

```
 class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
 {
  //add custom classes and attributes to menu
 }
```

You can read in more details about Custom Walker Function from here

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

Answer (score 0):

you can use the custom nav walker class and create the menu what you want following link where you understand the [nav walker class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker).

i have also implemented the bootstrap nav walker check the [following](http://icodehub.blogspot.in/2015/08/bootstrap-3-multilevel-dropdown.html).